# Subtracting time is giving me zero

Tags: excel, formula

I have a problem excel. I am trying to subtract two times in two different cells (Finish Time - Start Time) and it is giving me 0:00. What am I doing wrong?

I have changed the Custom formatting to [hh]:mm and it's still not working.
Let me note that each cell has a formula which evaluates the time according to other data on the sheet.

I expect that when I subtract 08:30 from 07:50 it should give me 0:40.

Comment: Which is exactly what I get.  please post the formula for those cells.

Comment: Then your time is stored as text and not numbers formatted as time.

Comment: The formula for the Start Time is 
    =IF(E3="","",IF(H3="",NOW(),H3))
The formula for the End Time is
    =IF(J4="","",IF(L4="",NOW(),L4))

Comment: ok and how is the time in H3 and L4, are they text or numbers?  If you change the format to `General` do they change or stay the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN6fY.png)

Go to Files > Options > Formulas > Enable Iterative Calculation

Answer (score 0):

> I expect that when I subtract 08:30 from 07:50 it should give me 0:40.

If you try to subtract 08:30 from 07:50 you should get `#########` because Excel does not show negative time.

Comment: Yeah I know but why is it giving me 0:00?

Comment: Now()-Now() is always going to be 00:00. Now() is volatile and recalculates automatically whenever anything in the workbook changes so you are **always** going to get 00:00. I honestly have no idea whatsoever how you are showing 08:30 and 07:50.